# Yii: How to get records from a CDataProvider , and how to echo record fields?

Tags: php, yii

I've a custom data provider in my Model

I tryied this in controller

```
public function actionMonthTotal()
{
    $model=new Rapporti();
    $this->render('monthTotal',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$model->monthTotal(),
    ));
}
```

Where monthTotal is the model function that give me a DataProvider

Actually 'monthTotal' is a copy/past of view.php and it uses a clistView using _monthTotal, that is a copy/past of  _view.php

I Need to simply get the dataset from dataProvider (a 'SELECT COUNT, SUM, SUM, etc...") and iterate into recordset to echo a simple TABLE into monthTotal view . So ...

**how to use a dataProvider from a view to get records and how to iterate trough recors?**

My month total is this and is in 'Report' Model

Actually report is in a relation Report N -> 1 Pionierato (sorry for italian terms, but are only object names)

```
public function totalMonth() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->with = array ('pionierato');
    $criteria->condition = 'dataBetel=:month';
    $criteria->select = "COUNT(t.id) as numProclamatori,
                            pionierato.tipo as tipoPionierato,
                            SUM(libri) as sommaLibri,
                            SUM(opuscoli) as sommaOpuscoli,
                            SUM(ore) as sommaOre,
                            SUM(riviste) as sommaRiviste,
                            SUM(visite) as sommaVisite,
                            SUM(studi) as sommaStudi";

    $criteria->group  = "t.dataBetel, t.pionieratoId";
    $criteria->params = array ('month' => "2012-09-01");

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Rapporti', 
                                           array ('criteria' => $criteria)
                                         );

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

I need to use this dataprovider to get the 3 record it will output and print a 3-row table. Static.

Using suggestion from first answer, i got this:

[image: Actual results]

Comment: Please show us your code from the monthTotal() function in your Rapporti model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
public function actionMonthTotal()
{
    $model = Rapporti::model()->monthTotal();
    $this->render('monthTotal',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

That should work, you are creating an object with the name $model which has a value equal to the return value of the method monthTotal() in the Rapporti model

If that doesn't work, check that you are actually getting a result from your monthTotal function by copying it (minus the return part) into your controller instead of calling it from the model.

In your monthTotal view you can iterate through the active records using [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) like so:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

Each iteration calls in a subview called "_view". The data for that record can be accessed using $data (eg: $data->id);

Here is an example of querying without using CActiveDataprovider:

```
$model = Rapporti::model()->findAll(array(
    'condition' => 'dataBetel=:month',
    ...
));
```

You can try that... Alternatively you can use findAllBySql() instead of findAll() and type in your query that way. You will then be able to iterate through your data set using a foreach() loop

Comment: ok, but this doesn't answer to my question: how to iterate over the $model in to the monthTotal and print every single fields ?

Comment: Ok, this work, but ... CListView show me ''77 results found' on top, no rows, and give me a paginator for 8 pages, and UNDER THIS it print the 3 records i've... 77 is the full tale of reports, 3 is the right recordset count from my dataprovider... I'll try to give you an image of the result

Comment: I added actual result using all of your suggestion

Comment: That is strange... what happens if you click on page 2 of the results? Maybe try starting with more simple criteria for your query and add  $criteria one by one, because it seems to be a problem with the query

Comment: i got this on page 2 http://imageshack.us/a/img834/9171/rpttemp2.png ... a lot strange ... Really.. is there a way to manually iterate over the dataprovider with a foreach and print the data without using the widget !?

Comment: You can do it without using CActiveDataprovider, but you will lose the pagination functionality that you get from CListView, will update my answer with an example

Comment: I doesn't need pagination. I always have 3 records only. What 'scary' me is the '1-3 of 77 results found' of clistview, so I prefer this time do make things manually. I'll try your updated answer

Comment: PS: $dataProvider->setPagination(false); :) but this show me ' total results 3', ok, but i want hide this .... I'm hateing list view !!

Comment: Easiest way to hide the results is with CSS (.summary {display: none!important;})

Comment: Thanks for all ! I give you 'good night' because here is about 11pm, and tomorrow we all will work ...

Answer (score 4):

I obtained the result in this way:

```
<?php 

foreach ($dataProvider->getData() as $id => $singleRecord) {
        $this->renderPartial('_monthTotal', array('data' => $singleRecord));
}

?>
```

and removing the clistview widget.

But your answer helped my a lot, so I'll give my preference to you, thanks !